# mysql performance_schema missing tables

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-server

Using mysql 5.6.19 on an ubuntu box, installed with `sudo apt-get install` and I am missing a few tables (got an alert from Workbench when trying to use the performance reports).

These are the tables that I do have in the performance_schema:

```
+----------------------------------------------+
| Tables_in_performance_schema                 |
+----------------------------------------------+
| cond_instances                               |
| events_waits_current                         |
| events_waits_history                         |
| events_waits_history_long                    |
| events_waits_summary_by_instance             |
| events_waits_summary_by_thread_by_event_name |
| events_waits_summary_global_by_event_name    |
| file_instances                               |
| file_summary_by_event_name                   |
| file_summary_by_instance                     |
| mutex_instances                              |
| performance_timers                           |
| rwlock_instances                             |
| session_connect_attrs                        |
| setup_consumers                              |
| setup_instruments                            |
| setup_timers                                 |
| threads                                      |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

From checking [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/performance-schema-statement-tables.html) I see that I am missing the following tables:

- performance_schema.events_statements_current
- performance_schema.events_statements_history
- performance_schema.events_statements_history_long
- performance_schema.events_stages_current
- performance_schema.events_stages_history
- performance_schema.events_stages_history_long

This is the output from show engines:

```
mysql> show engines;
...
*************************** 8. row ***************************
      Engine: PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA
     Support: YES
     Comment: Performance Schema
Transactions: NO
          XA: NO
  Savepoints: NO
...
```

Can someone please post the `show create table` statements so I can create them? and if you notice another table that Im missing I would very much appreciate the show create table for that as well

Answer (score 1):

The tables you have are from MySQL 5.5, the new tables in 5.6 are missing.

Please run `mysql_upgrade`.